# Can't get PhantomJS to work with a simple example

Tags: phantomjs

I've downloaded the executable and created a simlink to /usr/local/bin.

I'm under Mac OSX 10.7

When I then try to run a script that requires some module i.e.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
```

I got an error

```
undefined:0 ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

as if 'require' is not seen as a reserved word but interpreted as a variable symbol.

(As an aside, whenever I lunch phantomjs a Sencha Touch icon appears in my Dock)

Answer (score 4):

Your copy of PhantomJS is from an older version. Always get the latest one from http://phantomjs.org.

Comment: Of course that's were I got it. It was supposed to be version 1.5.0 but if I run the 'version.js' example I got 1.1.0. Otherwise, if i run phantom.version inside the REPL i got the 1.5.0. @Ariya Hidayat, Any comment about it?

Comment: Solved by just running the executable with ./phantomjs but cannot run it properly from the PATH after simlinking it into /usr/local/bin

Comment: Your PATH must be find another old version (installed somewhere in the system).

Comment: yes, indeed it was SenchaTouch which installed it :) I just removed it from my PATH, now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too, and the problem was my version of mocha -- going back to 1.9.0 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

SenchaTouch 2.0 installs PhantomJS 1.1 somewhere depending on the OS. Under *NIX check where with 'which phantomjs'.

Just modify your bash or whatever configuration file accordingly to remove the Phantomjs included with SenshaTouch from your PATH.