# mocha-phantomjs Can't find variable: require

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js

I am having the same issue as described here [Can't get PhantomJS to work with a simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520100/cant-get-phantomjs-to-work-with-a-simple-example) but the solution of having the right phantomjs version in my path doesn't seem to be fixing my problem.

I followed the tutorial here to a T:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/testing-javascript-with-phantomjs/?search_index=1

and it all works fine until I try to add require('webpage').create().

phantomjs version 1.8.1
mocha-phantomjs 2.0.0

What else could I be missing?

Comment: Which part of the example are you getting stuck and what exactly happens when it fails?

Comment: Example is not a problem, it works fine. The problem is when I try to use phantomjs stuff (ex. var page = require('webpage').create()). When I do this I get the error Can't find variable: require.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and the problem was my version of mocha -- going back to 1.9.0 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [require-stub](https://github.com/dfcreative/require-stub) in order to get `require` for testing needs.